# Bitcoin core synchronizing gets stuck on block

Tags: synchronization, block

I have bitcoin core version 25 and the blockchain is fully synchronized. Every 2-3 days I open up core to sync with the newest blocks. When i am syncing the newest blocks from the past few days the block just gets stuck randomly almost like core freezes. I don't get the spinning circle and if I quit core and reopen it thr blocks end up syncing. I used to be able to do this without it ever freezing like this.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: To diagnose the issue, you might want to look at the `debug.log` file in the Bitcoin data directory, to see if there are any error messages or warnings when the freeze happens. Feel free to post the relevant parts of the log here.

Comment: Would the fact that I have a firewall on my computer have any impact on my issue?

Comment: Your firewall settings could interfere with your node's ability to connect to peers and sync. However, if the issue is resolved by restarting, the problem might be due to software glitches or resource limitations on your computer rather than your firewall. Does the 'debug.log' reveal any suspicious details?

Comment: Opened the debug log but I'm not really sure what I'm looking for. I don't see anything that says failed

Comment: @deyw Hey Deyw, I looked further into the debug log. There is a part after the last block that synced it says the following: skipped DNS seeding, dnsseed thread exit. Imported mempool transactions from disk: 2876 succeeded, 359 failed, 0 already there, 0 waiting for installation broadcast. Does this help you at all?